# Button Text not displaying with kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm just starting to learn kivymd and am working through the tutorials online, but the buttons I create never now any of the text I define. The code I'm using down below is straight from kivymd's documentation and I'm not sure why the text won't show up. I've attached an image showing what I get when I build the app as well:

[button display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A902.png)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

class TestButtonApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        button = MDRectangleFlatButton(
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            text="MDRectangleFlatButton",
            theme_text_color="Custom",
            text_color="black",
            line_color="red"
        )

        return button

TestButtonApp().run()
```

Comment: When I run this on Windows I get text, so this code does not illustrate any problems. What OS are you running, versions, etc. ?

Comment: Ya know, I was running this on my Surface Pro X and when I ran it on my desktop there were no issues. I did have to download an OpenGL compatibility patch from my Surface to install kivy so I think this is the result of that. Thanks for the response!